# Getting empty string from fs.readFile inside chokidar.watch(path_file).on('change', ...)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, fs-extra, chokidar

I have the following very simple `Node` project:

https://github.com/tlg-265/chokidar-issue

[image]

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tlg-265/chokidar-issue
$ cd chokidar-issue
$ npm i
$ npm run watch-changes
```

which basically takes care of detecting changes on file:

`/profiles/bill-gates.json`

and do an action just after that.

In order to do that I have the following file:

`/profile-watcher.js`

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const colors = require('colors/safe');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');

const path_file = `profiles/bill-gates.json`;
console.log(`Current Profile: ${colors.red.bgBrightYellow(path_file)}`);

let profile_before = {};

chokidar.watch(path_file).on('change', async (path) => {

  console.log();
  console.log(`${colors.blue.bgYellow(`->`)} Profile changed: ${path}`);

  fs.readFile(path, (err, profile_json) => {
    console.log(`->${profile_json}<-`);
    let profile = JSON.parse(profile_json);
    if (JSON.stringify(profile) != JSON.stringify(profile_before)) {
      console.log('The profile has changed.');
      profile_before = profile;
    }
  });

});
```

when I run the project with:

```
$ npm run watch-changes
```

and do the modifications below on file: `/profiles/bill-gates.json`

- modification 1: `Bill Gates -> Bill Gates ABC`
- modification 2: `Bill Gates ABC -> Bill Gates ABC DEF`

it works fine, outputting the content of this file to the console.

But when I do the next modification:

- modification 3: `Bill Gates ABC -> Bill Gates ABC DEF GHI`

Then I get the following error:

```
-> Profile changed: profiles\bill-gates.json
-><-
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fs.readFile (\chokidar-issue\profile-watcher.js:17:24)
    at \chokidar-issue\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chokidar-issue@1.0.0 watch-changes: `node profile-watcher.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chokidar-issue@1.0.0 watch-changes script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-28T23_44_01_038Z-debug.log
```

`/profiles/bill-gates.json` (Flags: `UTF-8 / CRLF`)

```
{
  "name": "Bill Gates",
  "email": "bill.gates@microsoft.com",
  "password": "windows",
  "country": "USA"
}
```

By the way, if I change from `CRLF` to `LF` normally I can do few modifications more before it crashes.

I'm under the impression that for somre reason the file: `/profiles/bill-gates.json` gets locked at some point and when `Node` tries to read it it returns an empty string because it is locked.

Any idea on how to make this work without crashing after few tries?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/profiles/bill-gates.json`?  First, remove everything that is in it, then do a fresh run, then post the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work by adding some recovery fallback:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const colors = require('colors/safe');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const sleep = require('sleep');

const path_file = `profiles/bill-gates.json`;
console.log(`Current Profile: ${colors.red.bgBrightYellow(path_file)}`);

let profile_before = fs.readFileSync(path_file).toString();

chokidar.watch(path_file).on('change', async (path_changed) => {
  let profile = fs.readFileSync(path_changed).toString();
  if (IsValidJson(profile)) {
    if (profile != profile_before) {
      console.log();
      console.log(`Profile changed: ${colors.red.bgBrightYellow(path_changed)}`);
      process_profile(profile);
      profile_before = profile;
    }
  }
  else {
    sleep.msleep(100); // this is necessary
  }
});

function process_profile(profile_json) {
  const profile = JSON.parse(profile_json);
  console.log(`${profile_json}`);
  console.log(profile.name);
}

function IsValidJson(str) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(str);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

It seems that when you save a file (at least on Windows), sometimes there is a time in between (very very short time) that the file gets clear and few milliseconds later it gets the actual content. On both cases the `on-change` event gets fired. So, we just need to verify whether the content of the file is JSON or not. In that case I just need to ignore it and wait for the next `on-change` event.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you.

There is an option in "chokidar" where you can `awaitWriteFinish`. It's time-based and checks if the size of the file is changing. If not, then it will call the callback.

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch(configPathString, { 
    persistent: true,
    awaitWriteFinish: {
        stabilityThreshold: 500
    } 
});
watcher.on('change', (path, stats) => {

    fs.readFile(configPathString,(err, data)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        
        //console.log('data',data);

        let receivedData = JSON.parse(data);

        //Do whatever you like
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a race condition. Make your JSON.parse safe like this:

```
const path = require('path')

chokidar.watch(path_file).on('change', async (path) => {
  fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (err, profile_json) => {
    if (!profile_json) {
      console.log(`${path} is an empty file!`)
      return
    }
    const profile = JSON.parse(profile_json);
    if (JSON.stringify(profile) != JSON.stringify(profile_before)) {
      console.log('The profile has changed.');
      profile_before = profile;
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I just added `utf8` flag and the issue persisted. I also added your extra debugging logs (updated the repository) and it says the path exists. Also, bear in mind that the first 2 times I mentioned above it works properly but not third time. So why the path should be fine the first two times but not the third time?

Comment: Unable to reproduce using your repo. `System Version: macOS 10.15.3 (19D76)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 19.3.0`